# Adding new elements to my arraylist shows error

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add a new element into my arraylist but it shows er*or and I do not know why.
I have tried to change it but the error does not go away. I cannot think of saomething else.Plese help me if you want to fix it.
this is my code:

```
//main class
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Ticket {

    static ArrayList<T> arrayticket = new ArrayList <T>();   //T for Ticket( Generic Type)
public static void main(String[] args) {

 BuyTicket ticket1 = new BuyTicket();  
                ticket1.BuyaTicket();
}

class T {
    // instance variables
    private String type;
    private int RoutesOrDays;

    private String kind;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    private int TicketCode;
    private String ExpirationDate;




    //constructor
    public T(String type, int RoutesOrDays, String kind, String name, String email, int TicketCode, String ExpirationDate) {
        this.type = type;
        this.RoutesOrDays = RoutesOrDays;
        this.kind = kind;
        name = " ";
        email = " ";
        TicketCode = 0;
        ExpirationDate = " ";
    }
//++setters aand getters

}

public class BuyTicket extends MyInterface {

//METHOD
    int BuyaTicket() {
Save save_dataA = new Save();
                            save_dataA.Person3(type, hostOfRoutes, kind); 
     }
} 


public class SaveData extends T {
private String name;
    private String email;
    private int code;

    static AtomicInteger codeSequence = new AtomicInteger();  //Creates a new AtomicInteger with initial value 0

    //contructor
    public SaveData(String name, String email, int code ) {

        name =" ";
        email =" ";
        this.code = codeSequence.incrementAndGet();  //Atomically increments by one the current value.

    }

    //contructor of super 
    public SaveData(String type, int RoutesOrDays, String kind, String name, String email, int TicketCode, String ExpirationDate) {
        super(type, RoutesOrDays, kind, name, email, TicketCode, ExpirationDate);
    }

    void Person3(String type, int RoutesOrDays, String kind){    
        System.out.println("Type your full name.");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please type your email. ");
        String email = input.nextLine();
        code = codeSequence.incrementAndGet();

        arrayticket.add(new T(type, RoutesOrDays, kind, code,email, name));
//here is the er*or
    }
```

I am very new to java so what can I change in order to fix it???

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular How do [I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."
Please add the **complete error message**.

Comment: Do not use names like `T` for a *real* class. `T`,`S`, `K`, `V` etc are usually understood as "type variables" for generics, and using them as real types is confusing and unreadable. Besides, always give your classes, methods and variable meaningful names, and always follow the Java naming conventions. Method names should start with a *lowercase* letter. So `buyATicket`, not `BuyATicket`.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are new to java still you have decided to work with many classes, interfaces and some misconception of java generics. I decided to simplify your code as much as possible because *keep it simple* is a very good rule for programming.

I skipped your class BuyTickets since I didn't understand it and I moved `T` into the class `Ticket` and made it into the data class and then I let the `SaveData` class only have the responsibility to collect data.

There are still some oddities like some parameters I had to hardcode and you can only add one ticket but I hope this will help you move forward

SaveData class

```
public class SaveData {
    Scanner input;

    public SaveData() {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public Ticket buyTicket(String type, int routesOrDays, String kind) {
        System.out.println("Type your full name.");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please type your email. ");
        String email = input.nextLine();

        return new Ticket(type, routesOrDays, kind, name, email);
    }
}
```

and the main Ticket class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Ticket {
    static ArrayList<Ticket> arrayTicket = new ArrayList<>();
    private String type;
    private int routesOrDays;

    private String kind;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private int ticketCode;
    private String expirationDate;
    static AtomicInteger codeSequence = new AtomicInteger();

    public Ticket(String type, int routesOrDays, String kind, String name, String email) {
        this.type = type;
        this.routesOrDays = routesOrDays;
        this.kind = kind;
        this.ticketCode = codeSequence.incrementAndGet();
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        expirationDate = " ";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SaveData save = new SaveData();
        String someType = "type";
        int someRoute = -1;
        String someKind = "kind";
        arrayTicket.add(save.buyTicket(someType, someRoute, someKind));

        for (Ticket ticket: arrayTicket) {
            System.out.printf("Ticket [%d] for %s, %s\n", ticket.ticketCode,ticket.name,ticket.email);
        }        
    }
}
```